# confirm alert on cancel changes value of checkbox

Tags: angular

```js
item = {
  buyerAccept: null,
  buyerIncludeInProgram: false
};

remove() {
  if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return;
  else {
    this.item.buyerAccept = this.item.buyerAccept === true ? null : true;
    this.item.buyerIncludeInProgram = this.item.buyerAccept === true ? null : false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pretty p-default m-1">
  <input id="removeItemCheckbox" type="checkbox" [ngModel]="item.buyerAccept" (change)="remove()" />
  <div class="state p-warning">
    <label>Remove</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a checkbox binded to an object property.
When checking it, a confirm alert should appear and if the user click 'yes' I have to change some values in my code.
BUT if the users click on 'cancel' button, the checkbox value should not change.

i have also tried to use ngModelChange event but I have the same behaviour - on 'cancel' the checkbox value is still changed

Comment: Could you produce a minimal, reproductive example of your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this solution.

use `(click)` event instead of `(change)` event.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/confirm-alert-on-cancel-changes-value-of-checkbox)

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="pretty p-default m-1">
  <input id="removeItemCheckbox" type="checkbox" [ngModel]="item.buyerAccept" (click)="remove($event)" />
  <div class="state p-warning">
    <label>Remove</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
remove($event) {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        $event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        this.item.buyerAccept = this.item.buyerAccept === true ? null : true;
        this.item.buyerIncludeInProgram = this.item.buyerAccept === true ? null : false;
    }
}
```